# keystonejs cors error with middleware

Tags: keystonejs

I keep getting a CORS error when making an http req to keystonejs apis that work fine in the browser.  I added this middleware to middleware.js and it is getting called when making the request:

routes/middleware.js

```
exports.corsAPI = function (req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  keystone.initAPI(req, res, next);
};
```

and modified the routes/index.js

```
exports = module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/api/post/list', middleware.corsAPI, routes.api.posts.list);
    app.all('/api/post/create', middleware.corsAPI, routes.api.posts.create);
    app.get('/api/post/:id', middleware.corsAPI, routes.api.posts.get);
    app.all('/api/post/:id/update', middleware.corsAPI, routes.api.posts.update);
    app.get('/api/post/:id/remove', middleware.corsAPI, routes.api.posts.remove);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to just use the cors module instead of writing your own headers:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

In keystone.js:

```
keystone.set('cors allow origin', true);
keystone.set('cors allow methods', true);
keystone.set('cors allow headers', true);
```

In routes\index.js:
either:

```
app.get('/api/stuff', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.workshop.getStuff);
```

or:

```
app.get('/api/stuff', keystone.middleware.cors, routes.api.workshop.getStuff);
```

and all the other routes accordingly.
That's all that is necessary to enable CORS headers.